# Logarithm real analytic on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on a Tao Analysis II question. I have to prove that $log$ the inverse function of $exp$ is real analytic on $(0,\infty)$. I have already  proven that 
$$
 \forall x \in(-1,1): ln(1-x) = - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}
$$ and that
$$
\forall x \in (0,2): ln(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n (x-1)^n
$$
Does this help ? Further i may not make use of complex numbers.

Comment: You know how to show that $\log$ is differentiable with derivative $\frac1{x}$?  You know how to show that $\frac1{x}$ is real analytic?  You know how to show that an antiderivative of a real analytic function is real analytic?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Should be possible. 3) No :D But i will see if i can figure out your last point.

Comment: But this should be possible by some other method, since Tao has not mentioned your last statement earlier in the text.

Comment: André: True, it is possible by other methods, but have you seen term by term differentiation of power series?

Comment: I know the following: Given some real analytic function i know that the k-th derivative of that function is in terms of an real analytic function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $f'=g$ on an interval $(a,b)$, and $g$ is real analytic.  For each $c\in(a,b)$, there is an $r>0$ and a sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that for all $x\in(c-r,c+r)$, $g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n$.    The power series $h(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n+1}(x-c)^{n+1}$ also converges for $x\in(c-r,c+r)$, and $h'=g$ in this interval (this requires justification).  Therefore $f(x)=f(c)+h(x)=f(c)+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n+1}(x-c)^{n+1}$ for all $x\in(c-r,c+r)$ (e.g., this follows from the Mean Value Theorem).  This shows that $f$ is real analytic.

---

$g(x)=1/x$ is real analytic on $(0,\infty)$, because for each $c\neq 0$, $g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{c^{n+1}}(x-c)^n$ when $|x-c|<|c|$, by the geometric series identity. (More generally, you may have seen that a quotient of real analytic functions is real analytic away from zeros of the denominator.)

Comment: One question. You say by the mean value theorem. But then i wonder if this works, too: We assume $f' = g$ on $(a,b)$. Then $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = f'(z) = g(z)$ for some $z \in (c,x) \subset (c-r,c+r)$ if $x > c$ so that $f(x) = (x-c)g(z)+f(c)$ and thus is $f$ real analytic because $g$ is real analytic and $x-c$ is a constant. Is this true ?

Comment: @André: I don't have time to read or think about your comment, so I'll just briefly state that MVT implies that if $k'=0$ on an interval, then $k$ is constant, and as a consequence, if $f'=h'$ on an interval, then $f$ and $h$ differ by a constant (consider $k=f-h$...).

Answer (score 4):

Since I re-worked this example and was supposed to give the formal Power-Series $\sum_n c_n(x-a)^n$ which converges to $\log(x)$ if $|x-a| < R$ for some $R > 0$ I give my answer here:

We know that $x \in (0,2)$ implies

$$
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {{-1}^{n+1}}n(x-1)^n = \log (x)
$$

Let $z \in (a-a,a+a) = (0,2a)$ i.e. $R = a$. Then we have that $z = xa$ for some $x \in (0,2)$. Thus
$$
 \log(z) = \log(xa) = \log(a) + \log(x) = \log(a) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {{-1}^{n+1}}{na^n}(ax-a)^n 
$$ which equals
$$
 \log(z) = \log(a) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {{-1}^{n+1}}{na^n}(z-a)^n 
$$

Setting $c_0 := \log(a)$ and for $n>0$ $c_n:= \frac {{-1}^{n+1}}{na^n}$ we have 
$$
\forall a \in (0,+\infty) \forall z \in (a-R,a+R): \log(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(z-a)^n
$$ with $R > 0$ which proves that $\log$ is real analytic on $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: So you pick an arbitrary $z \in (0,\infty)$ and choose $a$ such than $z \in (0,2a)$. Does this not make your choice of $a$ dependent on $z$? Because then $(c_n)$ is not independent of $z$, which is not allowed in power series.

Answer (score 0):

We first establish that $\ln$ is real analytic at $x=1$ with radius of convergence $1$. We start from the geometric series $\forall x\in(-1,1), \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$

Integrate over $[0,x]$ on both sides, we obtain

$\forall x \in (-1,1), -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n }{ n} = \ln(1-x)$

This is equivalent to

$\forall x \in (0,2), \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{(x-1)^n }{ n} = \ln(x)$.

We then proceed to show that $\ln$ is real analytic over $\mathbf R$.

Let $b\in \mathbf R^+$ and $x \in (0,2)$.

Now $\ln (bx) = \ln b + \ln x = \ln b + \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (x-1)^n = \ln b + \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n b^{-n} (bx-b)^n$

Define $d_n := \ln b + c_0$ for $n=0$ and $d_n := c_n b^{-n}$ for $n \geq 1$,

Note that $\ln(bx) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n (bx - b)^n$. By definition, $\ln$ is real analytic at $b$ with radius of convergence $R := \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} |d_n|^{1/n}} 
=  \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} |c_n b^{-n}|^{1/n}} = b$.

Since $b$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $\ln$ is real analytic.